# Dataframe order misses up when copy data to another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df_reps that reads from csv

```
df_reps = pd.read_csv("c:\text.txt")
```

Here is how df_reps looks like

```
df_reps
Out[70]: 
         RepID                                                Txt
0            4  BLUE MAN SNACK BLUE YELLOW LONDON MAN LAPTOP A...
1           13  ALPHA MAN GREEN GREEN GREEN MAN STREET KITKAT ...
2           15  PLASTIC LONDON PARIS BLUE MAN TSHIRT FALCON  C...
3           16  STREET SNACK WOMAN LAPTOP LAPTOP GREEN BLUE MA...
4           18  JACK TSHIRT NANCY KITKAT MAN KITKAT YELLOW CAT...
       ...                                                    ...
122296  331787  MOVIE DVD WOMAN BLUE BLUE MCDONALDS HONDA KITK...
122297  331788  LAMP PIZZA APPLE MAZDA HONDA LIVE MAN BLUE FAL...
122298  331789  TREE MOVIE ALPHA DELTA PALESTINE BALL BLUE TAB...
122299  331790  TREE MAZDA NANCY RONALDO MAN KITKAT YELLOW FLO...
122300  331791  JACK JACK NANCY NANCY NANCY BALL YELLOW NANCY ...

[122301 rows x 2 columns]
```

labels df_results are read from another csv file

```
df_results = pd.read_csv("c:\labels.txt")
```

here is how it looks like

```
df_results
Out[71]: 
         RepID    ICU
0            4      0
1           13      1
2           15      1
3           16      1
4           18      0
       ...    ...
122296  331787      0
122297  331788      0
122298  331789      0
122299  331790      1
122300  331791      1

[122301 rows x 2 columns]
```

Due to dataframe is imbalanced

I used RandomUnderSampler and now things start to get missed up a little

```
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
df_reps, df_results = rus.fit_resample(df_reps, df_results["ICU"])
```

Due to undersampling the results of df_reps and df_results that become unsorted

here they are

```
        RepID                                                Txt
33266    90164  CAT GREEN HONDA HONDA KITKAT KITKAT HONDA NANC...
97472   264062  JACK FALCON KITKAT BALL BALL BLUE JACK FALCON ...
57080   154571  LAMP LAPTOP HONDA LONDON KITKAT HONDA KITKAT C...
64382   174131  KITKAT GREEN MAN MAN KITKAT KITKAT GREEN YELLO...
50312   135638  BALL HONDA FALCON DELTA DELTA FALCON KITKAT CA...
       ...                                                ...
122291  331782  RONALDO JACK DELTA VOLVO KITKAT LAMP LAMP HOND...
122292  331783  BALL UNDER KITKAT TREE GREEN ECHO JACK JACK IN...
122293  331784  VOLVO VOLVO CANADA LONDON KITKAT KITKAT RONALD...
122299  331790  TREE MAZDA NANCY RONALDO MAN KITKAT YELLOW FLO...
122300  331791  JACK JACK NANCY NANCY NANCY BALL YELLOW NANCY ...

[87148 rows x 2 columns]
```

you can see RepID is randomised now

and same to the df_results

```
df_results
Out[75]: 
33266     0
97472     0
57080     0
64382     0
50312     0
         ..
122291    1
122292    1
122293    1
122299    1
122300    1
Name: ICD10, Length: 87148, dtype: int64
```

the index between both dataframe seems matching

Now this part is going to make a big mess to the order

i have to Bag of word the dataframe

```
def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
  cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(),columns=CountVec.get_feature_names_out())
  return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)

dfMethod = BOW(df_reps["Txt"])
```

here is dfMethod

```
dfMethod
Out[76]: 
           BLUE       MAN     HONDA    KITKAT 
0             9         3         0         4 
1            48         3        11         8 
2            15         6        16         8 
3            30         6        11        12 
4            42         6        10         8 
        ...       ...       ...       ...     
87143        12         3         3         0 
87144         9         3         4         8 
87145        12         3         4         4 
87146        24        18        11         4 
87147        18        15         6        16 

[87148 rows x 100 columns]
```

index in dfMethod does not match index in df_reps nor df_results

**now what i want is to have RepID and ICU columns in dfMethod**

here is what i did

```
dfMethod["RepID"] = df_reps["RepID"].astype(int)
dfMethod["ICU"] = df_results.astype(int)
```

But... the result came out not in the same order

```
dfMethod
Out[85]: 
           BLUE       MAN     HONDA    KITKAT      RepID  ICD10
0             9         3         0         4       4.0    0.0
1            48         3        11         8      13.0    1.0
2            15         6        16         8      15.0    1.0
3            30         6        11        12      16.0    1.0
4            42         6        10         8      18.0    0.0
        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...    ...
87143        12         3         3         0  236157.0    0.0
87144         9         3         4         8  236159.0    0.0
87145        12         3         4         4  236160.0    0.0
87146        24        18        11         4  236161.0    0.0
87147        18        15         6        16  236166.0    0.0

[87148 rows x 102 columns]
```

you can see that RepID is not sorted ascending while it wasn't before.

now i am not sure if the RepID is assigned to its right feature set of BOW

anyone can help me link RepID to the right BOW features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should modify you `BOW` function to reuse the index of `df_reps`:

```
def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
  cv_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=Count_data.toarray(),
                              columns=CountVec.get_feature_names_out(),
                              index=df.index)  # <- HERE
  return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)

dfMethod = BOW(df_reps["Txt"])
```

Now indexes are aligned:

```
dfMethod["RepID"] = df_reps["RepID"].astype(int)
dfMethod["ICU"] = df_results.astype(int)
```

Comment: the indices get missed up at the UnderSampling process. any solution for that?